# PHP 3 Week Rotation of menus

Tags: php, calendar

I am working on a project, Where there is 3 set menus that roll
1:A 2:B 3:C

So in order to  accommodate this I tried to write a script that would know which week was what number (1-52)

```
    $firstDayOfMonth = '2014-01-01';    

    $week1 = $firstDayOfMonth;
    $week2 = date( "Y-m-d" ,strtotime('next Sunday', strtotime( $week1 ) ) );
    $week3 = date( "Y-m-d" ,strtotime('+1 week', strtotime( $week2 ) ) );
    $week4 = date( "Y-m-d" ,strtotime('+1 week', strtotime( $week3 ) ) );
    $week5 = date( "Y-m-d" ,strtotime('+1 week', strtotime( $week4 ) ) );
    $today = strtotime('today UTC');
```

I then used a simple echo to push out the following

```
    echo '
    Meals for Week starting ' .$week1 .' : Week A(code for menu list here)<br>
    Meals for Week starting ' .$week2 .' : Week B<br>
    Meals for Week starting ' .$week3 .' : Week C<br>
```

I then Decided that I would prefer to not have 52 instances of html strings.
so I tried to do something like this

```
if  ($today =='$week1' || '$week4' || '$week7' || '$week10' || '$week13' || '$week16' || '$week19' || '$week22' || '$week25' || '$week28' || '$week31' || '$week34' || '$week37' || '$week40' || '$week43' || '$week46' || '$week49'|| '$week52' ) {
echo "Display Week A$";
} elseif ($today == '$week2' || '$week5' || '$week8' || '$week11' || '$week14' || '$week17' || '$week20' || '$week23' || '$week26' || '$week29' || '$week32' || '$week35' || '$week38' || '$week41' || '$week44' || '$week47' || '$week50' ) {
echo "Display Week B$";
} else {
echo "Display Week C$";
```

I wanted to calculate the week by seeing which week today was in However running this always displays the if result.

I was wondering if any one could offer a better solution to my 2 month endeavor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$weekOfTheYear = date('W');

switch ($weekOfTheYear % 3) {
    case 1 :
        echo "It's the first week";
        break;
    case 2 :
        echo "It's the second week";
        break;
    default :
        echo "It's the third week";
}
```

Comment: I had tried this method however with it being the second week of January its actually the 1st week of the company, which is why i tried the longer assign a week to each of the 52 count method but maybe i am being stupid and should just use A as week 2 and then roll it forward that way.

Comment: So this is week should be just the first week of the year in your case, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

From the [php date documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

You can use date('W') to get the ISO-8601 week number of year

```
$currentWeekNumber = date('W');
```

You can then use [MOD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php) to compute if it is Week A, Week B or Week C.

```
switch ($currentWeekNumber % 3) {
    case 1 :
        echo "Display Week A$";
        break;
    case 2 :
        echo "Display WeekB$";
        break;
    default :
        echo "Display Week A$";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I finished with Thank you everyone for your input you guys are amazing.

```
$image1 = "<img src=img/weekc.png>";
$image2 = "<img src=img/weeka.png>";
$image3 = "<img src=img/weekb.png>";


 $weekOfTheYear = date('W');

 switch ($weekOfTheYear % 3) {
      case 1 :
    echo $image1;
    break;
case 2 :
    echo $image2;
    break;
default :
    echo $image3;
```